# Why Object.create is not creating new object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout in my project. I have an issue with the following code:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');

        function viewModelCollection() {
            var self = this;

            self.types = ko.observableArray([viewModel]);

            self.add = function () {
                //issue is here, the copy of viewModel object is adding
                //here, instead of new object.
                self.types.push(Object.create(viewModel));
            };

            self.remove = function () {
                self.types.remove(this);
            };
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new viewModelCollection());
```

Here i am getting an empty object from server through mapping plugin i am create the new viewModel object. I have also created the viewModelCollection which have and observable of viewModel and function operated on that array.

The issue is when i am adding new object in add function, it is not adding the new object instead it is copying the object. So in view if i change a value in a single text box it changes in all textboxes.

Why this line is not creating the new object :

```
Object.create(viewModel);
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a new instance of an object within itself.  self.add is a variable that evaluates itself, which is not an anonymous function, therefore it is being evaluated before the viewModel is fully instantiated.  At that point if you console.log(viewModel) it will return null or undefined.

This would be how you could use anonymous functions to create instances of a view model inside of a another view model

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var something = ko.observable();
}

function parentviewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var types = ko.observableArray();
    types.push(Object.create(viewModel));
    types.push(new viewModel());
}
```

But this would not work

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    var types = ko.observableArray();
    types.push(Object.create(viewModel));
    types.push(new viewModel());
}
```

Comment: please check my question again, i think you misunderstood

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding the difference between an anonymous function and a variable.

Comment: please check again viewModelCollection and viewModel are 2 different models and the add function is in viewModelCollection. So that's why i am not `creating a new instance of an object within itself`

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the difference for you application between copy of object and new instance of the object?
2. Why do you think it doesn't work? Check the `__proto__` field for the created object - there will be viewModel instance. `Object.create`  creates new object with the given object as  prototype. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's copying the object. You are telling it to copy the `viewmodel`, which is the same object you are binding against. If you want a fresh copy for each one, you need to keep the original copy fresh. The easiest way to do that would be to change the following line

```
self.types = ko.observableArray([Object.create(viewModel)]);
```

Now the first one put in the array is a copy, and the add function will continue to copy the original, and not the one that you are binding against. [See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/588kJ/1/).